# Help with zend framework setup?

Tags: zend-framework

I asked this question yesterday, looking if more people can help me out.

I installed the minimal zend framework on my freshly installed linux.

Using zf create project command I created a project, no errors inside the linux's html folder.

I go to localhost/projectname and it just opens up the project directory, once I go to public, it shows me the welcome to zend framework page (seems right, right?). I add a public action to indexcontroller but it doesn't link up with zend framework.

Can anyone explain the issue here or skype me at darius.coder ???

I've never been able to install a working installation of zend framework and only need to see it done once. Can anyone PLEASE help ? I have team viewer as well.

Comment: @darius What is the error you get? What do you mean by `it doesn't link up`? Also, if your project is setup properly, when you type `localhost/projectname` it should be showing you the project and not the directory listing

Comment: @JohnP I would expect it to show me the index.php file too, instead of the directory. When I say it doesn't link up, i mean if i create public function contactusAction() and insert a phtml file in the views section, and i type in localhost/projectname/(or add index/)contactus, it doesn't show up. I've followed every instruction that i could find online and it seemed the setup was full proof. The thing that I think can be the problem is I didn't edit any php.ini files other than what i was told online. I must be missing include_path or..? /var/www/html/projectname is my project location

Comment: You need to have modrewrite enabled and make the changes in your conf file as well. Have you done that?

Comment: @JohnP No I haven't. I followed these instructions http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-zend-framework-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/ I will look how to enable modrewrite right now. After that what do I do?

Comment: @JohnP Just looked it up, inside the httpd.conf file mod_rewrite is enabled, I didn't have to enable it.

Comment: Have a look at the Quickstart tutorial in their docs site : http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.create-project.html I used this when I set it up

Comment: Thanks. Guess I'll reinstall the OS and then work from there. I'll reinstall the OS, then I can go directly to installing Zend Server?

Comment: why do you want to reinstall the OS? You're trying to install Zend Framework right? Just create a new project. Make sure the library is added to the path

Comment: The thing you seem to be missing is that the `public` folder within your ZF app should be your document root (well, it's not required, but is the most logical choice anyway). So, just create a local domain (yourproject.local) point that to 127.0.0.1, create an apache VirtualHost which sets the document root to the public folder of your project (see [Creating A Local Domain Using Apache Virtual Hosts](http://www.survivethedeepend.com/zendframeworkbook/en/1.0/creating.a.local.domain.using.apache.virtual.hosts)).

Comment: Looks to me like @wimvds nailed it. If you set up a virtual host - which is the usual approach - named something like `myapp`, then it needs to point to the `public` folder, not its parent. Then you would access the app via: `http://myapp/` On the other hand, if you set up your project in a folder directly under your Apache root, then the top-level url for your app is `http://localhost/myapp/public/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have created your project via zf command

```
zf create project <project name>
```

You can create controller , action from the same zf command

```
zf create action <action name> <controller name>

zf create controller <controller name>
```

So in this way you don't want to create view pages etc . All will be done by zf tool .

Now coming to your problem .

As you told all is well until you created a public action in IndexController.php

So the url will be http://localhost/projectname/public/

Now when you created an action contact in IndexController

You can access via

http://localhost/projectname/public/index/contact

So what you was missing I guess is the public .

Let me know whether this helps you .

Thanks